# Duplicate list item in selectpicker beside jquery.steps

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I now used from `bootstrap.select` beside `Jquery.steps` plugin in my page(`ASP.NET MVC`).

My problem:

All select list that i make his with `bootstrap.select` are duplicate list, as well as duplicate item with text some belowe:

I put first `bootstrap.select.css` then `bootstrap.select.js` then `jquery.steps.js` and `jquery.steps.css` in my form.

How i solve this problem?

[image]

thnx friends.

Comment: It seems your data contains duplicate records. Make a fiddle if possible. Or debug to check the dropdown's datasource

Comment: I check 1000 times that.
When i remove css  `jquery.steps.css` it works good.